# Solidity inline assembly custom error revert foundry testing

Tags: solidity, testing, assembly, foundry

I have written test cases for the original high level code to test the reverting case of a custome error - `ERC20InsufficientBalance(address,uint256,uint256)` with the following code:

```
function test_transfer_with_insufficient_balance_reverts() public {
  uint256 amountToMint = 10_000;
  erc7629.mintERC20(address(0x1), amountToMint);

  vm.expectRevert(
    abi.encodeWithSelector(
      ERC7629.ERC20InsufficientBalance.selector, address(0x1), amountToMint, amountToMint + 1
    )
  );
  vm.prank(address(0x1));
  erc7629.transfer(address(0x2), amountToMint + 1);
}
```

Successfully passed the test case as wanted. However, i kept failing after updated the revert error line with assembly:

```
let ptr := mload(0x40)
mstore(ptr, 0xe450d38c) // `ERC20InsufficientBalance(address,uint256,uint256)`.
mstore(add(ptr, 0x04), from)
mstore(add(ptr, 0x24), fromBalance)
mstore(add(ptr, 0x44), value)
revert(ptr, 0x64)
```

Is it like the way it reverts was wrong or the test case should be changed to smth else. I've gone through different repo but failed to find one with foundry test cases that tested the custom error reverts.